# How to simulate computer crash in a unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, filesystems

In a C# .NET Core app I'm having some code that saves changes by appending data to a filestream and while doing that I would like to make sure that nothing can result in partially written bytes.

I was thinking about simulating crashes in a xunit test by running my code in a `Task` and kill that `Task` randomly to see how well it behaves. But `Task` does not have any killswitch and I can't really use `CancellationToken`s here. Thread used to have `Abort` but I can't find it in .NET Core. I guess they removed it. Any other options you can suggest that works in xunit? I could run the code in a separate process of course but I'm looking for some easier way of doing this.

I have read that append is atomic over the buffer length so if I have large enough buffer for the transaction I guess I will be safe? But I'd like to test this as well, under various conditions.

**Update**

I changed the title to not include the power failure case, just random crashes.

Also, if this cannot be avoided since writes just are'nt atomic as pointed out in the comments, any suggestions on how to make writes safer when dealing with append's? If I was (over)writing an entire file I could write it separately and then replace the old one when done (like ms office apps and other do), but when appending to a file I guess it becomes more complicated. Can I write separately and then in some way connect the two file segments atomically?

**Update 2**

I have at least solved how to really do atomic appends now if anyone wants to know. I just write the bytes as usual and when the transaction is done I update a position-pointer to where the last byte of the transaction is. Any bytes after this position I just ignore. Seems like the best option. But this was not the real question, which is how to simulate random crashes in a xunit test.

Comment: Just don't. Thread.Abort is not the same as power failure. Appending to a buffer cannot be an atomic operation since it takes more than one assembly instruction to achieve. It can be locked so that no one else tries to use the buffer at the same time but the power failure still can happen when you are in the middle of writing. Also I believe Filestream buffers even if the data is written to buffers it does not mean it will be flushed to actual file if the file is not closed properly (e.g. as a result of power failure). Now you have tow operations - write and flush - non-atomic for sure.

Comment: Nice question. A unit test is supposed to return a result reliably. Random crashes fail this expectation.